# why does this error happen in Keras,"Graph disconnected" when I want to separate whole network into two models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have an autoencoder in keras and I need to define a different model for each part because my network has two outputs and I want to have two separate network for each output during the test, but when I do this it produces the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 99, in 
>       wext=Model(inputs=decoded_noise,outputs=pred_w)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py",
>   line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 93, in **init**
>       self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 231, in _init_graph_network
>       self.inputs, self.outputs)
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
>   line 1443, in _map_graph_network
>       str(layers_with_complete_input))
>
> ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor
>   Tensor("input_8:0", shape=(?, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32) at layer
>   "input_8". The following previous layers were accessed without issue:
>   []

I want to have two networks during test one of them from the encoder to end of the decoder and second for w extraction part. what is the problem? Thank you.

```
#-----------------------encoder------------------------------------------------
wtm=Input((28,28,1))
image = Input((28, 28, 1))
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(image)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(conv2)
BN=BatchNormalization()(conv3)
encoded =  Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='encoded_I',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BN)


add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
encoded_merged = add_const([encoded,wtm])

#-----------------------decoder------------------------------------------------
deconv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(encoded_merged)
deconv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv1)
deconv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='convl3d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv2)
deconv4 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='convl4d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv3)
BNd=BatchNormalization()(deconv3)

decoded = Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='decoder_output',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BNd) 

model1=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=decoded)

decoded_noise = GaussianNoise(0.5)(decoded)

#----------------------w extraction------------------------------------
convw1 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl1w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(decoded_noise)
convw2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw1)
convw3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl3w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw2)
convw4 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl4w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw3)
convw5 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl5w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw4)
convw6 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl6w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw5)
pred_w = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='reconstructed_W',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw6)  
wext=Model(inputs=decoded_noise,outputs=pred_w)
final=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=[decoded,pred_w])
```

**Modified code:**

```
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, GaussianNoise,Cropping2D,Activation,Dropout,BatchNormalization,MaxPool2D,AveragePooling2D,ZeroPadding2D
from keras.layers import Conv2D, AtrousConv2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras import backend as K
from keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import keras as Kr
from keras.optimizers import SGD,RMSprop,Adam
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import keract
from matplotlib import pyplot
from keras import optimizers
from keras import regularizers

from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Lambda;
w_expand=np.zeros((49999,28,28),dtype='float32')
wv_expand=np.zeros((9999,28,28),dtype='float32')
wt_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(49999,4,4))
wt_random=wt_random.astype(np.float32)
wv_random=np.random.randint(2, size=(9999,4,4))
wv_random=wv_random.astype(np.float32)
w_expand[:,:4,:4]=wt_random
wv_expand[:,:4,:4]=wv_random
x,y,z=w_expand.shape
w_expand=w_expand.reshape((x,y,z,1))
x,y,z=wv_expand.shape
wv_expand=wv_expand.reshape((x,y,z,1))

#-----------------building w test---------------------------------------------
w_test = np.random.randint(2,size=(1,4,4))
w_test=w_test.astype(np.float32)
wt_expand=np.zeros((1,28,28),dtype='float32')
wt_expand[:,0:4,0:4]=w_test
wt_expand=wt_expand.reshape((1,28,28,1))
#-----------------------encoder------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wtm=Input((28,28,1))
image = Input((28, 28, 1))
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(image)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(conv2)
BN=BatchNormalization()(conv3)
encoded =  Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='encoded_I',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BN)


add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
encoded_merged = add_const([encoded,wtm])

#-----------------------decoder------------------------------------------------
deconv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(encoded_merged)
deconv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv1)
deconv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='convl3d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv2)
deconv4 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='convl4d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv3)
BNd=BatchNormalization()(deconv3)

decoded = Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='decoder_output',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BNd) 

model1=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=decoded)
decoded_input=Input((28,28,1))

#----------------------w extraction------------------------------------
convw1 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl1w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(decoded_input)
convw2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw1)
convw3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl3w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw2)
convw4 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl4w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw3)
convw5 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl5w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw4)
convw6 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl6w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw5)
pred_w = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='reconstructed_W',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw6)  
decoded_noise = GaussianNoise(0.5)(decoded)
wext=Model(inputs=decoded_input, outputs=pred_w)
pred_w = wext(decoded_noise)

w_extraction=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=[decoded,pred_w])
#----------------------training the model-----------------------------------

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()
x_validation=x_train[1:10000,:,:]
x_train=x_train[10001:60000,:,:]
#
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_validation = x_validation.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format
x_validation = np.reshape(x_validation, (len(x_validation), 28, 28, 1))

#---------------------compile and train the model------------------------------
opt=SGD(momentum=0.99,lr=0.0001)
w_extraction.compile(optimizer='adam', loss={'imageprim':'mse','wprimmain':'binary_crossentropy'}, loss_weights={'imageprim': 1.0, 'wprimmain': 1.0},metrics=['mae'])
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=40)
#rlrp = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=20, min_delta=1E-4, verbose=1)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('los4x4_con_tile_convolw_FBN_SigAct_SandPAttack.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
history=w_extraction.fit([x_train,w_expand], [x_train,w_expand],
          epochs=1,
          batch_size=32, 
          validation_data=([x_validation,wv_expand], [x_validation,wv_expand]),
          callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/home/jamalm8/tensorboardGNWLoss/', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False),es,mc])
w_extraction.summary()
```

the produced error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 113, in 
>       w_extraction.compile(optimizer='adam', loss={'imageprim':'mse','wprimmain':'binary_crossentropy'},
>   loss_weights={'imageprim': 1.0, 'wprimmain': 1.0},metrics=['mae'])
>
> File
>   "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 119, in compile
>       str(self.output_names))
>
> ValueError: Unknown entry in loss dictionary: "imageprim". Only
>   expected the following keys: ['decoder_output', 'model_29']

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `decoded_noise` is not an Input layer so you can't you it as input when defining your `wext` model. Instead, define a new input layer for your `wext` model:

```
#----------------------w extraction------------------------------------
# Here we define a new input to be used by the wext model
decoded_input = Input((28,28,1)) 
convw1 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), ...)(decoded_input)
convw2 = ...
...
pred_w = ...

wext=Model(inputs=decoded_input, outputs=pred_w)

# Final model: pass the gaussian noise through the wext model
decoded_noise = GaussianNoise(0.5)(decoded)
pred_w = wext(decoded_noise)

final=Model(inputs=[image, wtm], outputs=[decoded, pred_w])
```

Comment: I modified the code based on your suggestion, but it produces the above error. I know why has this error occurred, but I'm not sure it performs as before I did not separate the network? is it possible to send the output of a model to the loss function? we usually send the output of layer into the loss function?!

Comment: You should post this as a separate question since it has nothing to do with your original question. If you want to use multiple losses you can check out this guide: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/04/keras-multiple-outputs-and-multiple-losses/. Short answer: You need to add a name to your output layers (for example 'imageprim' and 'wprimmain') and then use this name when you define the losses. You should also provide this name to your input data when fitting the model.