# is it possible to send the output of batch normalization to the next layer instead of Activation output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have an autoencoder with two outputs and the first output should be used as an input to the next part of autoencoder after some changes. I put my code here and I'm a little confused that this code is logically true or not. in the following code I have one output in `decoder` part named `act11` the output of sigmoid activation and the second output is in the `w extraction` part with name `pred_W`. I feed `bncv11` to the `GaussianNoise` instead of `act11`. I want to know it is correct or not? based on back propagation rules and the structure of the network is it possible to do this? can I just use the output of activation in this code `act11=Activation('sigmoid',name='imageprim')(bncv11)` for the output of model?
all of my questions is about this part of the code:

```
decoded = Conv2D(1, (5, 5),  padding='same', name='decoder_output',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BNd) 
bncv11=BatchNormalization()(decoded)
act11=Activation('sigmoid',name='imageprim')(bncv11)
decoded_noise = GaussianNoise(0.5)(bncv11)

#----------------------w extraction------------------------------------
convw1 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl1w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(decoded_noise)
watermark_extraction=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=[act11,pred_w])
```

I want to know the above code based on deep learning is correct or not?
I just use `act11` in the activation and for output but use `bncv11` for feeding during learning.

```
wtm=Input((28,28,1))
image = Input((28, 28, 1))
conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(image)
conv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e',dilation_rate=(2,2))(conv2)
BN=BatchNormalization()(conv3)
encoded =  Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='encoded_I',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BN)


add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
encoded_merged = add_const([encoded,wtm])

#-----------------------decoder------------------------------------------------
deconv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(encoded_merged)
deconv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv1)
deconv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='convl3d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv2)
deconv4 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5),  activation='relu',padding='same', name='convl4d',dilation_rate=(2,2))(deconv3)

BNd=BatchNormalization()(deconv3)

decoded = Conv2D(1, (5, 5),  padding='same', name='decoder_output',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BNd) 
bncv11=BatchNormalization()(decoded)
act11=Activation('sigmoid',name='imageprim')(bncv11)
decoded_noise = GaussianNoise(0.5)(bncv11)

#----------------------w extraction------------------------------------
convw1 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl1w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(decoded_noise)
convw2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw1)
convw3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl3w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw2)
convw4 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl4w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw3)
convw5 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl5w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw4)
convw6 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conl6w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw5)
pred_w = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='reconstructed_W',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw6)  

watermark_extraction=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=[act11,pred_w])
```

Comment: "I want to know the above code based on deep learning is correct or not?" Honestly, I could not understand what you mean by this. Obviously, you can connect a layer to any other layer as long as they have compatible output/input shapes. However, whether a particular connection makes sense (i.e. increase the performance or accuracy of the model) depends on intuition or common sense, or it can only be verified by experimentation. With a quick look at your code, I couldn't spot something terribly wrong (though, it's a bit complex!). So you must experiment with it on some data to find the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. because my accuracy has become very good and I was worried it is wrong to do not send the output of activation to the next layer and it does not participate in backpropagations and just remember the input. I have another question too. if I want to separate my network to two networks that one from first of network to act11 and the next model from w extraction part to end, what should I do? I want to do this for test time. because during test time I need to feed an attack image for example with JPEG to w extraction part

Comment: but during training, I do not have an Input layer for it and the output of decoded_noise will feed to this part. so when I produce a model with decoded noise as input it produces an error like a disconnected graph. I asked this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699907/why-does-this-error-happen-in-keras-graph-disconnected-when-i-want-to-separate/55702782#55702782 but I could not find my answer.

Comment: sorry, you said it is a bit complex this means it has bad or maybe can do wrong? because I am a beginner.